# Can´t send post wirth javascript to another page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I´m trying to send the variable idValue to a class called cambio_prenda.php with the following code

```
 function reply_click(clicked_id)
  {
      var idValue = clicked_id;
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'cambio_prenda.php',
            data:{"cambio" :idValue},
            success: function(response)
            {
              alert("exito");
            }

       });
  }
```

This code works when i use it in the same class, but when I try to call it from the another class with this code it doesn´t work

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['cambio'])){
$item = $POST['cambio'];
echo($item);
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont understand why you using $_GET when your ajax working with $_POST

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake making tests, I tried it this way

Comment: Have you tried check network using dev tool?

Comment: There is no obvious reason for failing. Unless sharing more of your code or error we can't really help. I've noticed that you use echo with parentheses but echo() is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it.

Comment: `try to call it from the another class` - do you mean you try to use `$_POST['cambio']` in another PHP file?  If yes, how is the other file included in the file you are POSTing to (`cambio_prenda.php`)?  `it doesn´t work` - that does not tell us much.  What happens?  Please edit your qeustion and add some details, it is very hard to understand what you have, and what are trying to do.

Comment: The first sniped of the code is coming from a class called index.php, when I send the post to index.php it works. The problem is when y try to send it to cambio_prenda.php (another class in the same directory)

Comment: Check your browser's devtools.  Is the POST really happening?  Is the status OK/200? Click the request and look at the request body - is `cambio` really there? Also, you haven't shown us how `reply_click()` is fired?  See how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).